# The two box stereo example is not working in the Samsung Internet browser in GearVR

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am using the Samsung Internet Browser in GearVR with webVR enabled. I have taken the code for the "two boxes, one in each eye" example directly from the github source.  It should show one box in each eye. But no matter what I have tried I get both boxes in each eye or something worse. Nothing I have tried produces the correct result.

My ultimate goal is to use webVR to play 360 3D videos (from VUZE) in stereo in webVR. But I cannot get even this simple stereo app to work. Any suggestions for the best way to get stereo VR to work in an HMD, especially GearVR would be greatly appreciated.

The source is the two boxes example from https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component

the code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My A-Frame Scene</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/latest/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="aframe-stereo-component.js.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-sky color="#FFF"></a-sky>
        <a-light color="#333" position="0 5 0" type="ambient" intensity="0.2"></a-light>
        <a-light type="point" color="#EEE" intensity="1.0" position="3 3 10"></a-light>

        <!-- 'left' eye entities will pass trough the camera in non-VR mode -->

        <a-camera position="0 0 10" cursor-color="black" stereocam="eye:left;"></a-camera>

        <!-- in VR mode, the first box is displayed only in the left eye, the second one in the right eye -->

        <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #C03546" stereo="eye:left"></a-entity>
        <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #3546C0" position="0 5 0" stereo="eye: right"></a-entity>

    "</a-scene>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I tried on a DayDream with a Pixel 2 and all examples worked as expected.

Comment: I used Daydream and Pixel 1 and chrome 64.0.3282.137.  I see both boxes in both eyes.  Is there something wrong with my code? some special setting for chrome? Does it only work for Pixel2? Is there a URL with the 2 box example? (I've been posting a copy of the code on my website.)

Answer (score 0):

I can"t get the Samsung VR browser to work correctly for any example, not even Samsung's.

I use the Oculus Carmel browser for all WebVR on Gear VR.

Comment: Thanks.  But I installed Carmel  in GearVR ran it and tried all the buttons, including Navigate, and could not find any way to access a URL for a webvr enabled page, which is what I am trying to do.  .... I want to view The page www.qporitxr.com/twob/twob.html  -- which should appear as a red box in the left eye and a blue box in the right eye.

Comment: I'm able to load www.qporitxr.com/twob/twob.html in Carmel, and the goggle button appears in the lower left corner of the page.  However, clicking the goggle button puts Carmel in a weird mode I haven't seen it do before, which looks a lot like Samsung VR.  You might start from a different example, such as https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/  or use the latest stable version of A-Frame: <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

The code showed above comes from the documentation at https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component.

A working example is at http://oscarmarinmiro.github.io/aframe-stereo-component/ .

Looking at the source code for http://oscarmarinmiro.github.io/aframe-stereo-component/two_boxes/index.html reveals that both the script lines in the head
should be replaced by the one line

```
<script src="../build.js"></script>.
```

build.js and correct versions of the index files are in the code files in https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component, but not in the documentation below it.